# How to find Third Z with 3D Line with 2 3D Points and 1 Known 2D Point

Tags: math, 3d

I am trying to solve this, but not lucky:

```
$p1 = [0,0,0]; // x,y,z
$p2 = [20,10,1]; // x,y,z
$p3 = [30,15]; // x,y

$p3z = calc_z3($p1,$p2,$p3);
```

How to calculate the Z of P3?

Comment: based on what? are some properties of the line known? if not the your missing coordinate can be any number ...

Comment: Not any number, it is a 3d line; all the points have to be in a straight line in 3d space. See the solution below...

Answer (score 1):

I see it like this:

```
l12 = sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 )
l13 = sqrt( (x3-x1)^2 + (y3-y1)^2 )
z3 = z1+((z2-z1)*l13/l12)
```

so:

```
                  | (x3-x1)^2 + (y3-y1)^2 |^0.5
z3 = z1 + (z2-z1)*|-----------------------|
                  | (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
function calc_y3 ($x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$x3) {
    $m = ($y2 - $y1) / ($x2 - $x1);
    $b = $y1 - $m * $x1;
    $y3 = $m * $x3 + $b;
    return $y3;
}

function calc_z3 ($x1,$y1,$z1,$x2,$y2,$z2,$x3,$y3) {
    $x = $x2-$x1;
    $y = $y2-$y1;
    $z = $z2-$z1;
    if ($x == 0 and $y == 0) // it's a point
        return $z1;
    if ($x == 0) // it's a 2d line
        return calc_y3($y1,$z1,$y2,$z2,$y3);
    if ($y == 0) // it's a 2d line
        return calc_y3($x1,$z1,$x2,$z2,$x3);
    $t = ($y3-$y1)/$y;
    $z3 = $z1+$t*$z;
    return $z3;
}
```